# Why I can't change user image on Android project

Tags: java, android, chatsdk

I am trying to create a android chat app for college and I am learning from [chat21](https://github.com/chat21/), which has an [chat sdk](https://github.com/chat21/chat21-android-sdk) project and [chat demo app](https://github.com/chat21/chat21-android-demo), and I'm basing my app from these 2 projects and everything works except changing user profile picture from that icon to a image from phone, so could anyone know why...

......................................................................................................

Here is the [acticvity_public_profile.xml](https://github.com/chat21/chat21-android-sdk/blob/master/chat21/src/main/res/layout/acticvity_public_profile.xml) located on chat21 sdk

Here is the [PublicProfileActivity.java](https://github.com/chat21/chat21-android-sdk/blob/master/chat21/src/main/java/org/chat21/android/ui/users/activities/PublicProfileActivity.java) located on chat21 sdk

......................................................................................................

Here is the [fragment_user_profile.xml](https://github.com/chat21/chat21-android-demo/blob/development_v2/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_user_profile.xml) located on chat21 demo app

Here is the [UserProfileFragment.java](https://github.com/chat21/chat21-android-demo/blob/development_v2/app/src/main/java/chat21/android/demo/UserProfileFragment.java) located on chat21 demo app

......................................................................................................

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid linking to your source code (there are many users who are not trusting external links) and include the *relevant* pieces of code in your question. Also, have a look at [how to create a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

In the demo project, user data will be stored in contacts node in firebase database. Like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XohL.png)

Here, you can see that there is no value stored in imageurl. so you will not get any image in profile section.

In your custom project, you can change it and pass firebaseauth.getcurrentuser().getprofilepicurl() to fetch the user profile pic url.

Comment: i am unable to handle chat21 sdk it show ....core.ChatManager$Configuration$Builder: Configuration.Builder: appId = null
I/TAG_TOKEN: RefreshFirebaseInstanceIdTask: token == null
I/CHAT21_D_LOGIN: SaveFirebaseInstanceIdService.onTokenRefresh:user is null. token == cpgkmCOlYd0:APA91bEm_enUuk8LrdX5fevZIgwX-BSh8yTrDQ1XScnXzAzipNu67KNk7sPDCyqojI395htP3mkTYNJCz9pE0DnceLYpK-WsYpuGkLf4N7w6FBBMhupogEJ_wsNNv, appId == null